# How to customize or remove extra Linux kernel version details shown at boot?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

For this kernel version string (displayed on boot):

Linux version 3.12.18 **(vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64) (gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) )** #1 SMP Thu May 1 18:56:23 UTC 2014

How can the part in bold be removed or customized as part of the kernel build?

Answer (score 4):

You can customize parts of your version string you wish to edit (seen at boot or by invoking the command `cat /proc/version`) by setting the following defines:

- `KBUILD_BUILD_USER` to change your "vagrant" value.
- `KBUILD_BUILD_HOST` to change your "vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64" value.

You may also be interested in `KBUILD_BUILD_TIMESTAMP` (changes "Thu May 1 18:56:23 UTC 2014") and `KBUILD_BUILD_VERSION` (changes "#1").

---

The complete Linux process banner is finalized in [init/version.c](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/init/version.c). The values of these defines are generated by [scripts/mkcompile_h](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/scripts/mkcompile_h). You could edit either of these files to have full control of your version string, but you never know when this additional information might be helpful; I would recommend only altering the defines. Another option is to [make some changes your host system](http://tjworld.net/wiki/Linux/Kernel/Build/CustomiseVersionString) to override generated values. By doing this, you're adding additional build maintenance just to change a rarely queried value.

Comment: I wish there was a way to store the git commit of the kernel automatically but I can't find it besides doing the `git log %H` myself :-(

Answer (score 1):

Kernel provides the below info only to user-space via uname call. You can seegcc version **gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)** only in customized uname binary/kernel.

## man 2 uname

```
               struct utsname {
                   char sysname[];    /* Operating system name (e.g., "Linux") */
                   char nodename[];   /* Name within "some implementation-defined
                                         network" */
                   char release[];    /* Operating system release (e.g., "2.6.28") */
                   char version[];    /* Operating system version */
                   char machine[];    /* Hardware identifier */
               #ifdef _GNU_SOURCE
                   char domainname[]; /* NIS or YP domain name */
               #endif
               };
```

Fedora/Redhat does not display compiler information.

```
[root@Shash Sasi]# uname -a
Linux Shash 3.13.10-200.fc20.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Apr 14 20:34:16 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

And **vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64** looks like EXTRAVERSION is kernel main makefile.

```
VERSION = 3
PATCHLEVEL = 15
SUBLEVEL = 0
EXTRAVERSION = -rc3
```

In init/version.c:

```
const char linux_banner[] =
        "Linux version " UTS_RELEASE " (" LINUX_COMPILE_BY "@"
        LINUX_COMPILE_HOST ") (" LINUX_COMPILER ") " UTS_VERSION "\n";

const char linux_proc_banner[] =
        "%s version %s"
        " (" LINUX_COMPILE_BY "@" LINUX_COMPILE_HOST ")"
        " (" LINUX_COMPILER ") %s\n";
```

Also refer fs/proc/version.c

Comment: Sure, but this doesn't answer me how to change this. And remember I'm talking about the first line being output by the kernel on boot, not uname once the system has started.

Comment: Modify Makefile to remove (vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64) and do check uname source on ubuntu to find where does it comes. I think If you compile vanilla kernel you wont see this.

Comment: My build is based on a clean download from kernel.org. EXTRAVERSION is empty, so this is not it.

Comment: In init/version.c: 

const char linux_banner[] =
        "Linux version " UTS_RELEASE " (" LINUX_COMPILE_BY "@"
        LINUX_COMPILE_HOST ") (" LINUX_COMPILER ") " UTS_VERSION "\n";

const char linux_proc_banner[] =
        "%s version %s"
        " (" LINUX_COMPILE_BY "@" LINUX_COMPILE_HOST ")"
        " (" LINUX_COMPILER ") %s\n";

Comment: @Axel: comment section is messy so I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
make menuconfig -> General setup -> Local version - append to kernel release
```

that is `CONFIG_LOCALVERSION` in the `.config` file.

Comment: No, this is not it. If I had a local version -lv it would print Linux version 3.12.18-lv (vagrant...