# Compiling a kernel

Tags: linux-kernel

I had to compile my kernel because I added a new system call to the kernel. i follwed the exact steps mentioned on this website https://tssurya.wordpress.com/2014/08/19/adding-a-hello-world-system-call-to-linux-kernel-3-16-0/

My kernel finished compiling but does not show version as linux-3.16 but shows linux-3.16.0-30-generic instead. am i not booting into my rebuilt kernel? or if not what is the error?

Comment: You could get the time stamp of the kernel build by the command uname -a

Comment: You cant boot into your new kernel? The reason probably is, you did not use correct configuration of your hardware. Just copy `/boot/config-<any>` to `.config` in your kernel sources and restart from `make menuconfig`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just open Makefile in the linux kernel_src/Makefile and check the "EXTRAVERSION" information. 
It may be the "EXTRAVERSION" is added.

Answer (score 0):

The kernel version is build from some more parameters. Have you checked your settings for EXTRAVERSION?

[How can the Linux kernel version extra details be customized or removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23424174/how-can-the-linux-kernel-version-extra-details-be-customized-or-removed)